# Line bundles of degree (g-1) on a smooth projective curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g>2$ over an algebraically closed field $k$. Does there exist a line bundle $L$ on $X$ of degree $(g-1)$ such that $H^0(X,L)=0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locus of $L$ with $H^0(X,L) \ne 0$ is the image of the natural map $X^{g-1} \to Pic^{g-1}(X)$. Its image is at most $(g-1)$-dimensional, hence its complement is nonempty.